# Question list not showing "X New Questions" on StackOverflow

Tags: bug

The last couple days I've noticed that I'm not getting the "X New Questions" notification anymore. Is this a result of the changes that were made fairly recently, and can we expect this back?

Comment: Yes. I forgot I checked that box a while back, and failed to make the correlation between the two. My apologies.